# what is the latex cls search order

Tags: cls

I have make the folder in macOS 13.3 like this:

```
/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/texmf/tex/latex
```

then I put the `zheyuyesetting.cls` in this folder and compile the latex file, shows error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `zheyuyesetting.cls' not found.
```

the `zheyuyesetting.cls` file was a custom class file that I write, I do not put it into system class. because the file will use in different folder, I do not want to put it into compile folder that will dulplicate when compile tex file. I need to put it into user system folder. is it possible to put the custom class tex file into user system folder? what should I do?

Comment: Is the texmf known to your tex system? Did you e.g. run something like `tlmgr conf auxtrees add /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/texmf`  ?

Comment: as you are on Mac os it should be located in `/Users/xiaquiangjiang/Library/texmf` rather

Comment: On a mac local stuff goes in `~/Library/texmf`